# Report Formula errors - multiple conditions in the IF Statement

Tags: formula, report-formula

I am trying to create a formula field that evaluates the lapsed donor status.

If (FY1>0 && FY0=0, "Lapsed FY0", "Returned Donor")

The above formula works but when I try to determine the lapsed status for each of the last 3 FY I get various errors from missing ",", etc.

[image: error message]

Comment: The first step everyone should take when trying to debug formulas is to follow [Formula Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_formula_best_practices.htm&type=5). Putting everything on its own line and indenting appropriately generally makes it very easy to spot issues like missing parenthesis and extra commas.

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to contain the entirety of the formula that's giving you issues. Images are not very accessible, and make it harder for people to make corrections for you (i.e. you're forcing people to re-type your entire formula instead of copy/pasting it and making minor changes). The easier you make it for people to help you, the better your chances of getting a response.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are mixed up. The extra parentheses at position 3 (`IF((`, the second parentheses) causes the first comma to become part of the condition statement. If we shorten this logic to show just Boolean and parentheses, we get:

```
IF( (X && Y, Z), 
  IF( X && Y, Z ), 
  Z
))
```

Hopefully it should be much more obvious what's gone wrong.

Your parentheses need to be organized to match the following pattern:

```
IF( X && Y, Z,
  IF( X && Y, Z, W )
)
```

There should be precisely four parentheses in total in your formula.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!